# Form not showing the variable from previous form

Tags: c#, winforms

I got five forms that show one by one: Form1 > Form2 > Form3 > Form4 > FinalForm.

Every one has a textbox and a Next button. My problem is that I can't get the variable from the textbox in Form1 to show it at FinalForm (the last one) in the label6.
What is the problem?

Form1:

```
namespace DaneUzytkownika2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Nazwisko nazwisko = new Nazwisko();
    private string imie;

   public string UstawImie
    {
        get
        {
            return imie;
        }
        set
        {
            imie = value;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UstawImie = textBox1.Text;
        Hide();
        nazwisko.ShowDialog();
    }
}
}
```

Last form:

```
namespace DaneUzytkownika2
{
    public partial class KoncowaInformacja : Form
    {
        public KoncowaInformacja()
        {
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void KoncowaInformacja_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            label6.Text = form1.UstawImie;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a whole new instance of `Form1`. Why would you ever expect this is going to contain data from a completely different instance of `Form1`? If you want to pass data from one form to another, just *pass them*. For example,  as an argument to the constructor, or by making your own `ShowDialog` method.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form = new Nawisko(textBox1.Text);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's passing the textBox1.text to the second form (Nazwisko), not the last one (KoncowaInformacja). How do I pass it to the last one? I've tried `var form = new KoncowaInformacja(textBox1.Text);`, but then I get an error because of null value.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzczepankiewicz You haven't shown enough of your code to say anything specific, but the main idea is that you simply have to pass it wherever you need it to go. If that means you need to pass it three times through three different forms, that's what you have to do. Try reading up a bit on the difference between types and instances to get a clearer picture of what is happening - I assume you come from a Delphi/Visual Basic background?

Comment: Uhm, I don't need it on every step. I just need it to pass to the last one. First > last, second > last, third > last, fourth > last, and last shows values of all the textboxes. That's why I'm stuck, I know how to pass a value to a next one, but I've failed trying to make it work for the last one. Okay I will watch a course for instances and types.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzczepankiewicz Sure, so pass it through all of the different forms. There's many ways to do that, nobody says you have to pass each piece of data separately - maybe you can pass a couple of `struct`s, or a mutable object. Or just make the final form the main form, and have it launch all the different dialogs in a sequence - this will give you trivial access to data from each of the forms. Using a sequence of `this.Hide(); next.ShowDialog();` is probably a bad idea anyway. There's many specific solutions, but they all boil down to the same thing - pass the data.

Comment: Uhm, the point is, that it have to contain 5 forms, and each one of the first 4 has to send one textbox data to the last one. And it has to be shown 1>2>3>4>last. I would to this differently, but it has to look like an installation wizard (one by one). Is there also another solution to make it look like this, without using `this.Hide(); next.ShowDialog();` as you mentioned?

Comment: @KrzysztofSzczepankiewicz One solution is to use a different form / piece of code to handle the sequence, as I noted in my previous comment. You want a *sequence* of forms, not a matrioska of forms :) The code would look something like `form1.ShowDialog(); form2.ShowDialog(); ...` (with cancel/error handling, of course). Another would be to use some wizard control or, for example, a `TabControl` or something similar.

Comment: oh now I got it. The matrioska example visualized it. Thank you. I will use the TabControl because it's much easier, but I will want to learn the dialogs in the future. I will try to google it. Anyway, thanks!